# Google Maps API with Geolocation and Places Search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps and places API. I'm trying to have the map show current location WITH surrounding restaurants, cafes, and bars. At this point the map loads and the geolocation is working. I can't seem to get the place markers to show up. I have no idea what I'm missing as I'm learning javascript as quickly as possible.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank You!

Here is my current code:

```
<script>   
var map;
var service;
var marker;
var pos;
var infowindow;

function initialize() 
{

    var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 14,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     scrollwheel: false,
     panControl: false,
     streetViewControl: false,
     mapTypeControl: false,
     };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    //HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
       {
            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map,position: pos,content: 'You Are Here'});

            var request = {location:pos,radius:500,types: ['restaurant, cafe, bars']};

            map.setCenter(pos);

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request,callback);

        }, 

        function() 
        { 
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

    function callback(results, status) 
    {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) 
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
        {
          createMarker(results[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    function createMarker(place) 
    {
      var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
    {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your script call to the Google API includes a reference to the places library. For example:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourAPIkey&libraries=geometry,places&sensor=true&language=en"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy! I did have a reference to it, but for the heck of it I added your line. Still nothing, same exact outcome.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then. I've added your code to JSFiddle and before I changed the external resources to account for it, JSFiddle was throwing an error that it couldn't find places. Adding it in made the error go away (http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/a3DC6/)

Comment: Hmmm. I just don't get it. It obviously loads fine, and geolocates fine, it's just not finding places from the search and dropping pins. I can get the two parts to work by themselves, just not together like this.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It's in this line: var request = {location:pos,radius:500,types: ['restaurant, cafe, bars']}; it has to be var request = {location:pos,radius:500,types: ['restaurant', 'cafe', 'bars']};

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
var request = {location:pos,radius:500,types: ['restaurant, cafe, bars']};
```

instead of `types:` write `keyword:`